# Batch clear operation not work under RBAC mode with airflow 1.10.2

Tags: python, airflow, rbac

I find batch task instances clearing from web UI not work when I enable RBAC .

I just upgraded airflow to the latest stable version 1.10.2, and enabled the RBAC mode . But I cannot clear the task instance from web UI. E.g. there are 10 failed tasks in DAG A， and I can't clear all of them once. The only way to clear it from web UI is to go into the DAG Graph View， then click *"failed tasks"* and clear them one by one.

But it works fine if I disable RBAC.